# Finding paths of length k

Tags: algorithm, graph, hadoop, mapreduce

Given a graph with n nodes there are a number of  serial methods of increasing sophistication and reducing complexity for finding simple paths of length k in a graph. The best known asymptotic complexity is currently [O(2^k poly(n,k)) time](http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.3026).  A naive algorithm on the other hand just enumerates all paths of length k and takes O(n^k) time (at least).

How could you translate the naive algorithm to work efficiently in the MapReduce paradigm?  Are there existing libraries for this sort of thing?

Comment: This doesn't warrant its own answer, but there's [Apache Giraph](http://giraph.apache.org/) for working with Graphs on Hadoop, which is probably helpful for this task.

Answer (score 0):

MapReduce is a parallelization framework, so the algorithm must be susceptible to parallelization to some extent, i.e. we can divide processing of solution space to independent sets. 
I guess that for the naive algorithm, you can tell each node to find k-1 long paths that begin with fixed graph node. For simplicity, if we have n machines, each of them can search k-1 paths that begin with 1, 2, ..., n. Of course parallelization gives only constant time improvement.